# HDD not accepting Password

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, passwords, password-recovery, password-protection

I have `Dell Inspiron 6400` and my `Hard disk (Seagate)` was password protected. Now suddenly my HDD not accepting password (even though I know the password). I tried my `HDD` into another Laptop but result was same. Always showing Invalid Password.
 Can anyone suggest me what needs to be done for the same

Comment: Send it to a professional for password removal

Comment: There is a utility called "HDD Unlock Wizard", don't know if is any help. Also see http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/askjack/2010/apr/09/laptop-hdd-password-locked

Comment: Did you ask Dell? They may have a support option for that.

Comment: And I found this weird support forum: http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f36/dell-hd-bios-passwords-free-1074297/

Comment: @JanDoggen, Thanks for reply but HDD Unlock Wizard not work with usb and I am not able to login in my Lappy.